# On window load, but at least

Tags: jquery, timer, preloader

i've mad a simple preloader which disappears on window load function.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#loading').animate({
        opacity: 0
    },1000,'easeInQuint',function() {
        $('#loading').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

How can i made to disapear #loading on $(window).load(); but if load is faster, disapear at least after 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You'd wanna start with your $('#loader') visible on the page,  then keep it there using a timer and a variable that has the window's load state.

Your JS would look something like this:

```
var t = setTimeout('hideLoader()', 6000);

var loaded = false;
$(window).load(function() {
    loaded = true;
});

function hideLoader() {

    if (loaded == true) {
        $('#loaded').hide();
    } else {
        t = setTimeout('hideLoader()', 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: thnx, i've tryied it but it gives me an error "hideLoader is not defined"

Comment: this isn't a working solution,  it's a suggestion.  Don't use it as-is.   Anyway, for that specific problem you'd move the "hideLoader()" function to be above the "var t = setTimeout..." part.